# Zend Server CE php myadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, zend-server-ce

Hi i am new to zend framework,To start with i have downloaded the zend community server.I have also created a projectand managed to run the sample guestbook application.But when i try to open phpMyAdmin it asks for user name and password.In my phpMyadmin folder there is a file called config.inc.In that it shows that username is root and there is no password set.

when i try to login with those credentials that is username as root and password i keep it blank i get an error #2003 Cannot log in to the MySQL server.

How can i solve that?
Thanx in anticipation

Comment: This question doesn't relate to zend framework at all

Answer (score 0):

Try to open cmd and run "mysql -uroot mysql" and leave password empty. If it will not help, then try "1234" - but this password was actual only for 2009 ZendCE and it has to be set "". If you will succesfully log in, then check your phpmyadmin config whether there are some options like $cfg['Servers'][$i]['nopassword'] or $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword']. Should be set to true

Also there is some option (I don't remember excat name) about allow root to connect with blank password. Try to look something like AllowNoPasswordRoot or AllowBlankRoot...

Answer (score 0):

I was also having the same problem, but mine started after finishing the installation and not being able to run the server installation wizard in the browser.

So after googling around for a day I decided to uninstall all, download the alternate version of `Zend` with `PHP 5.2` and before double clicking on it to run it I selected to run in as an administrator.

It did the same process of installation but at the end it all worked perfectly. The username for the phpMyAdmin is "*`root`*" with blank password.